# Where to check iAd revenue?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I integrated iAds in my app, however I am not sure how to check the iAd revenue. In iTunes Connect, I don't seem to find any place to find my revenue. From research about the new iTunes Connect, few posts suggested https://iad.apple.com/

But when I try to login with my developer Id, it just loops back to the same login page again without any errors or anything. I have tried Safari 8.0.2 and Firefox 37.0.1

Does anyone else have this issue? Or do I need to do something special to get access to the site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. Try http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Looks like it's down right now, I can't access it either.

Comment: i logged into http://iad.apple.com to see my iads revenue and ad related metrics

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see any income / revenue on the *Sales & Trends* or the *Payments* sections.

You should some more research before asking though...